# Adding time to time in R

Tags: r, datetime

Dates and times are so confusing in R. I just want to randomly generate some 24 hour clock times and then add to them.

The random generation:

```
library(lubridate)

hourTime <- as.list(format(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()),
                                    as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+1),
                                    by = "5 min"),
                         "%H:%M", tz="GMT"))
```

Trying to convert into a Date:

```
df$ARRIVALTIME <- replicate(1000, sample(hourTime, 1, replace=F))
```

Trying to add to the previous time:

```
df$TRETTIME <- df$ARRIVALTIME +
    (hours(sample(1:3, 1000, replace=T)) + minutes(sample(1:60, 1000, replace=T)))
```

This fails I guess because I don't have a time formatted object. How can I add random times to the `ARRIVALTIME`?

Comment: Where do `hours()` and `minutes()` come from? Did you write those? Why do you have `as.list()` for the `hourTime`?

Comment: @MrFlick. Those are from lubridate (updated the code). as.List is so I can sample from it.

Comment: `hourTime` is just a list of character strings isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the *format* function, you create a character variable that cannot be sum. Therefore, I would suggest to keep then as POSIXt and use as character when necessary

Also, the *minutes* and *hours* functions from lubridate create a **period** object that is converted to a number when in a list (I don't completely understand this part here) and I could not sum using lists.

Anyways, if I understand propperly, I have manage to get the results you wanted by working with no list (you can put the results after on one, if you may) with the code:

```
hourTime<-(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()),
                         as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+1),
                         by = "5 min"))


ARRIVALTIME <- sample(hourTime, 1000, replace=T)
TRETTIME <- ARRIVALTIME +
    (hours(sample(1:3, 1000, replace=T)) +
                     minutes(sample(1:60, 1000, replace=T)))
```

Comment: instead of replicate(1000, sample(hourTime, 1, replace=F)) I have used sample(hourTime, 1000, replace=T) which I guess works in the same manner. both works

Answer (score 8):

It is simpler -- the underlyng `POSIXt` is either the long-form / by-element `POSIXlt` (not useful here) or the compact `POSIXct` -- which is just a double (aka `numeric`) -- which which you can do 'Math'.

So create time anyway you want, then just add real values:

```
R> now <- Sys.time()
R> set.seed(123)
R> deltas <- cumsum(rnorm(5))    # just five N(0,1), added up 
R> 
R> now
[1] "2018-06-14 16:50:36.55687 CDT"
R> 
R> now + deltas
[1] "2018-06-14 16:50:35.996404 CDT" "2018-06-14 16:50:35.766226 CDT"
[3] "2018-06-14 16:50:37.324935 CDT" "2018-06-14 16:50:37.395443 CDT"
[5] "2018-06-14 16:50:37.524731 CDT"
R>
```

Once you understand the base types, there is little need for add-on packages 
as everything just works in (fractional) seconds.  So to add an hour, it is 60*60 and so on.  Add-on packages are still useful *business-day* conventions, holidays and additional parsers.

Your problem in your code snippet was that the `format()` destroys the `Datetime` object: you asked R to create a string, which it did.  On those you no longer can do math.  Ergo, do the math first, then pretty-print or format.

Comment: Not to forget trusty old `as.difftime` - `Sys.time() + as.difftime(1, units="days")` if you want to make added units (days/hours/minutes/seconds) explicit.

Comment: Sure, but OP asked for randomness.