# adding time in R dataframe

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

This question similar with this post
[Adding time to time in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50866366/adding-time-to-time-in-r)
but has any specific.
Say i create dataframe

```
a=9658
b=9658
e=9658
d=9658
dat=cbind(a,b,e,d)

the result
            a         b            e           d
1        9658        9658         9658      9658
```

i need create new colomn with date when data was create

I.E output

```
   a   b       e   d    dateload
  9658 9658 9658 9658   01.10.2018 00:00
```

in sql this function called `getdate()`

Comment: Do you need `Sys.time()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sys.time()` will give you this.

Hope this helps.